# Injecting Doctrine Entity into Symfony controller based on route parameters

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, controller, entity

I want to inject Doctrine entities into controller actions based on the route parameters in an attempt to reduce the insane amount of code duplication inside my controllers.

For example I have the following route

```
product:
    path:     /product/edit/{productId}
    defaults: { _controller: ExampleBundle:Product:edit }
```

Instead of my current approach

```php
public function editAction($productId)
{
    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $product = $manager->getRepository('ExampleBundle:Product')
        ->findOneByProductId($productId);

    if (!$product) {
        $this->addFlash('error', 'Selected product does not exist');
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('products'));
    }

    // ...
}
```

I'd like this to be handled else where as it's repeated in at least 6 controller actions currently. So it would be more along the lines of

```php
public function editAction(Product $product)
{
    // ...
}
```

It seems this has in fact been done before and the best example I can find is done by the SensioFrameworkBundle http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html

I'd use this but were not using annotations in our Symfony projects so need to look at alternatives. Any suggestions on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Make yourself a controller product listener which listens for routes with productId and loads the product. Might take a bit to get working (hint inject your product repository) but it's a useful technique once mastered.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) carefully, you'll learn that param converters actually work without annotations:

> To detect which converter is run on a parameter the following process is run:
>
> - If an explicit converter choice was made with @ParamConverter(converter="name") the converter with the given name is chosen.
> - Otherwise all registered parameter converters are iterated by priority. The supports() method is invoked to check if a param converter can convert the request into the required parameter. If it returns true the param converter is invoked.

In other words if you don't specify a param converter in an annotation, Symfony will iterate through all registered converters and find the most appropriate one to handle your argument (based on a type hint).

I prefer to put an annotation in order to:

- be explicit
- save some processing time

Comment: Thanks for this, after working for almost 13 hours straight it was far too easily to miss this! All working perfectly now!