# Cannot autowire argument $article : Symfony 5

Tags: symfony

I'm currently facing to this error when I try to get my article page : `Cannot autowire argument $article of "App\Controller\HomeController::show()": it references class "App\Entity\Article" but no such service exists.`

I just created a very new small symfony 5 application :
The code in my controller is :

```
/**

 * @Route("/show/{id}", name="show")
 */
public function show(Article $article): Response
{
    if(!$article) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
    }
    
    return $this->render('show/index.html.twig', [
        'article' => $article,
    ]);
}
```

I am following a tutorial on Udemy and I guess that I did the same thing as the former. Maybe version difference ?

Comment: This functionality is provided by the [SensioFrameworkExtraBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html).  It should be installed and configured automatically assuming you used 'symfony new --full project' to create your project.  And of course you need to have doctrine properly installed and configured though again this should all happen by default.

Comment: Well I did not use --full when i created the project. Thanks a lo ! it works now :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Injecting Doctrine Entity into Symfony controller based on route parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570343/injecting-doctrine-entity-into-symfony-controller-based-on-route-parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you have is saying that it cannot find the auto-wire path to your entity. Using the [Symfony installer](https://symfony.com/download) will automatically configure parts like this for you.

The main part which auto-wires the Entity to the Dependency Injection layer is through Doctrine configuration and the [Symfony ParamConverter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) found as part of the [SensioFrameworkExtraBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html).

The ParamConverter has a lot of options to be able to convert parameters inside of the `@Route` into an Entity. Using your example above we see that Symfony will internally call `ArticleRepository->findOneById($id)` and return the result to your controller.

EDIT: Removed all mentions of Doctrine configurations. The errors that are displayed when Doctrine is not auto-wiring are different.

Comment: Please share more details - this is only the configuration for Doctrine itself. How does this affect routing? Why not recommend to install `sensio/framework-extra-bundle`  which contains the needed ParamConverter?

Comment: I have fixed it adding far more details. This would have been all avoided had OP used the [Symfony Installation](https://symfony.com/download) instructions which auto-completes all of these configuration details for them

Comment: What makes you think that the Doctrine configuration itself caused the problem?

Comment: Yeah, i solved the problem by simply installing `sensio/framwork-extra-bundle`, thanks a lot guys :)

Comment: @NicoHaase I've removed all mention of the Doctrine auto-wiring. That has different errors which state it cannot find the Entity. It's similar to the error which Thierry mentioned. I've cleaned up my answer.